# How to parse xml in groovy without XmlParser and XmlSlurper

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have to read an XML file and modify some tags from JSON changeable values in Jenkins.

Both `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser` are not whitelisted in my Jenkins config (i can't change this). I tried to parse myself using DOMBuilder but it's also not permitted.
Is there any way to edit my XML referring to an external script?

Comment: funny that you excluded all standard ways to parse xml in groovy without using external libraries. the other way is not to parse it, but to work with xml like with a string and replace parts of it with replaceAll() function...

Comment: Just ask your Jenkins server admin to approve `XmlSlurper` or `XmlParser` classes. The default Jenkins settings are very defensive, and approving any of the two classes do not introduce any security vulnerability. Most of the Groovy classes require manual approvement, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't use them. Maybe excluding some of the classes/methods that may break the Jenkins (like process manipulation or something like that). Parsing XML does not apply to this category.